# Locations truncated when load GPX file

Tags: android, android-studio, gpx

I want to load this GPX file on android emulator to simulate a route.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxedw="http://www.gpxeditor.co.uk/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxedts="http://www.gpxeditor.co.uk/xmlschemas/TrackSegExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" creator="GPXEditor" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk>
    <name>Untitled</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="46.20425" lon="6.18676" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20424" lon="6.18674" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20463" lon="6.18597" />
      <trkpt lat="46.2049" lon="6.18521" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20496" lon="6.18503" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20517" lon="6.18401" />
      <trkpt lat="46.2054" lon="6.18277" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20558" lon="6.18195" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20584" lon="6.18094" />
       ...
    <trkpt lat="46.20874" lon="6.14039" />
      <trkpt lat="46.20879" lon="6.14046" />
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

But the loading truncate to integer all locations :
[image: Location simulation truncated]

I have try some online editor to make this GPX file, and always the same issue occurs :

- http://www.gpxeditor.co.uk/
- https://wtracks.appspot.com/

Comment: Question: what is a decimal separator in Switzerland ... maybe google fu* up parsing as they did in Vector drawable

Comment: Thank you ! The decimal separator in Switzerland is the point for currency values, and ... comma for other values. Replace all points by commas fixes the issue.

Comment: You should report it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) ... They should use neutral locale for decimal parsing...